# Talmudic Terminology

Tags: adult-learning, words, talmud-gemara

There are a number of English language works which to one degree or another discuss Talmudic terminology, i.e. the wider implication of certain phrases commonly used in the Gemara. Can anybody suggest traditional works from which these are derived, in particular those which might be hiding in some of the "supplemental" material at the end of various mesechtos?

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of "what's the distinction between "meisvei", "ibaya lehu", "rami", and "maskif la"? "

Comment: Yirmiyahu, I just added another source (with a link) that is quite user friendly, even in its original print.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Here is an exhaustive (but not necessarily complete) list of earlier lexiconic sources for Talmud:**

**[Sefer HaAruch](http://hebrewbooks.org/43084)**, Rabbeinu Nasan Ben Yehiel,

**[Sefer HaTishbi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/42662)** from R' Eliyahu Bachur, or this [link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/42661)

**[Sefas HaYam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40697)**, or this [link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35762)

**[K'lalei HaTalmud](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/24850)** of Rav Yosef Karo,

**[K'lalei HaTalmud](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/38786)** of Rav Betzalel Ashkenazi,

**In the back of any Vilna Edition of Maseches B'rachos,**

**[M'vo Hatalmud](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/11511)**, (R' Shmuel HaNagid)

**[Sefas Chachamim](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/10.pdf)** by Aaron Yelinek, which is a dictionary of difficult Persian and Arabic words found in the Talmud and Midrashim.

**K'lalei HaTalmud**, of the K'neses HaG'dolah, Rav Chaim Benveniste. (Link not available yet.)

**[Yad Malachi](http://hebrewbooks.org/32530)** (I just had a senior moment. Thank you WAF!)

(There is a new print available of [Yad Malachi](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&numPageStartPosition=3061&P_ID=3539&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=86) by Mishor

I have it and use it often. )

Another favorite of mine is **[Darkei Noam](http://hebrewbooks.org/42077)** by R' Shlomo Di Oliveira,

Answer (score 4):

It seems the original question wanted English books. I always like the Frank dictionary for that. But in the spirit of the other answers with Hebrew books, I would recommend Otzer HaTalmud, or Encyclopedia Talmudit

Comment: The original question wanted the sources for these English books.

Comment: Yes, but looking back at it I can tell I wasn't entirely clear

Answer (score 4):

halichos olam, the shelah,  sdei hemed

מההרי נמרים לרבנו עמנואל הספרדי

כללי הגמרא להרדב”ז
דרכ’ התלמוד לרבינו יצחק קנפנטון

Answer (score 2):

Try Yad Mal'achi (see [here](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0013_0_13079.html)).